# I get an error for sending push for IOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

**The error:**

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in
>   /home/####/public_html/####/testpushnotification.php on line 28
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in
>   /home/####/public_html/####/testpushnotification.php on line 28 Failed
>   to connect: 0

**Here is my code:**

```
$apnsPort = 2195;
$badgecount = 1;

  $streamContext = stream_context_create();
  stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);
  $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
   if (!$apns)
   {

  exit("Failed to connect: $error $errorString" . PHP_EOL);
} else
{
    $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $message,'badge' => $count, 'sound' => 'default');
    $output = json_encode($payload);

   $token = pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken));

   $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . $token . chr(0) . chr(strlen($output)) . $output;
   fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) tutorial for Push notification. check certificates and there is one reference php code file you can check or use that file to check push notification.